# Search and edit line(s) in python source (.py) files

Tags: python, replace, keyword

I want to search for a specific line in a python source code file (.py) via keyword matching and edit the found line, but also be able to edit the before and following line. Everything of that programmatically, so that I can automize it.

Is there a framework, tool or anything else to do that?

To be more specific:

I have to decorate methods. I've got a list (that I already converted to a XML-file) of all methods and their associated decorators. As I have 500 methods, it would take too much time too do that manually. That's why I want to find a way to that automized.

Example:

**XML-File**

```
<methods>
   <method>
      <name>method_1</name>
      <decorator>xyz</decorator>
   </method>
   <method>
   ...
</methods>
```

**Source Code**

Before the automized search end edit algorithm:

```
def method_1():
  ...
```

After the successful algorithm:

```
@mark.xyz
def method_1():
  ...
```

Comment: Do you have a current `.py` file, a keyword you want to match, and what you want to insert into the current/previous/post line? Or would you like just a generic model of this?

Comment: Also those downvotes are probably due to the nature of the format of your question, usually you want to post some piece of code and an objective with a desired output, paragraphs of texts with no code usually don't receive a warm welcome but I think I can help you with this

Comment: I have several .py files. I have a list of methods that need to be marked with decorators like "@mark.xyz". I have 500 of these methods and it would be a pain in the ... to that manually.

Comment: Or even an example like post one `.py` file and then what you would want it to look like after being altered

Comment: Did it. And thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about something along these lines of this, I included a `replace` and `insert` function for whichever you need to do for the specific task. Also you can use `with` to avoid having to `close` and bundle it all in there, honestly it could use some more refactoring but didn't want to go to far if this didnt satisfy your needs.

*Added if statement, this will stop your entire file from being wiped by the `w` option if you don't match a keyword and return an error.

```
def find_edit(content, keyword):
    for i in range(len(content)):
        if content[i] == keyword:
            previous_line = i -1
            main_line = i 
            post_line = i + 1 
            return previous_line, main_line, post_line

def replace(position, replacer):
    content[position] =  replacer

def insert(position, insertion):
    content.insert(position, insertion)

filename = open('something.py', 'r')
content = filename.read().split('\n')
prev, main, post = find_edit(content, 'line 3')
filename.close()

if prev and  main and post:
    name = open('something.py', 'w')

    something = '@mark.xyz'
    replace(main, something)

    prev, main, post = find_edit(content, 'another_line 2')
    insert(post, something)
    content = ('\n').join(content)

    name.write(content)
    name.close()
```

**Output**

Before :

> ```
> (xenial)vash@localhost:~/python/LPTHW$ cat something.py
> line 1
> line 2
> line 3
> some_line 1
> some_line 2
> some_line 3
> another_line 1
> another_line 2
> another_line 3
> ```

After:

> ```
> (xenial)vash@localhost:~/python/LPTHW$ cat something.py
> line 1
> line 2
> @mark.xyz
> some_line 1
> some_line 2
> some_line 3
> another_line 1
> another_line 2
> @mark.xyz
> another_line 3
> ```

Comment: Your answer was the solution. Thank you! I refactored it :) If anyone wants the solution I used, I can post it in here.

Comment: Glad that worked out, cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a framework, tool or anything else to do that?

Among other solutions you can use Emacs

From the [FAQ](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/efaq/Replacing-text-across-multiple-files.html)

> **5.37 How do I perform a replace operation across more than one file?**
>   Dired mode (M-x dired , or C-x d) supports the command dired-do-find-regexp-and-replace (Q), which allows users to replace regular expressions in multiple files.